# Extra ":" at the end of output from sudo su -c ls, only when globbing is used

Tags: android, sh, adb, glob, ls

Using adb shell to run commands on an android device, I get different results when running `ls` with or without a wildcard ( globbing, i.e `*` ).

When running ls without a wildcard, the last path is displayed properly. When running ls with a wildcard, the path is displayed with an `:` in the end of it for some reason. The actual file does not have a `:` in its path.

My issue is specifically with the last file: `/data/data/com.kauf.wrapmyFaceFunphotoeditor/files/DV-com.com.kauf.wrapmyFaceFunphotoeditor-2020-05-17-17-44-30-DEBUG.txt:`

it has an `:` in the end which isn't supposed to be there

Why does using a wildcard in `ls` add characters to the result path?

Edit, environment details: Windows 10 / Android 7, the code is running on sh. I've ran `adb shell` to get to this command prompt, and doing it in one line (i.e `adb shell su -c ls ...`) returns similar results, same for `adb shell command ...`; also clarified the question.

Comment: `ls` doesn't do wildcard handlng at all. bash changes `ls *.txt` to `ls a.txt b.txt c.txt` before `ls` is even started. (This is unlike Windows, where command-line parsing is done by the program being started, even if usually by some standard-C-library bits that the user doesn't write or have control of unless they make an active attempt to do so).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I understand, so ls runs separately on each one of these because of globbing; however, I still dont understand why ls on the folder would return a different name than ls on the file within that folder. Do you know why that happens?

Comment: ...beyond that, the question of why `ls /tmp/a` returns `/tmp/a`, whereas `ls /tmp` just returns `a`... well, that's normal `ls` behavior; it's what it's _always_ done. Do I need to go find the POSIX spec where it's defined?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy my issue is specifically with the last file: /data/data/com.kauf.wrapmyFaceFunphotoeditor/files/DV-com.com.kauf.wrapmyFaceFunphotoeditor-2020-05-17-17-44-30-DEBUG.txt:

it has an `:` in the end of it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy question edited, also I've checked, the filename does not have an actual `:` in it; it is as shown when I run the `ls` without the wildcard.

Comment: (btw, as an aside, `ls` generally [shouldn't be used programmatically at all](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); if output is for a script's consumption rather than a human's, `printf '%s\0'` is very much the better tool, as it can unambiguously represent all possible filenames in a form that doesn't change based on exactly which vendor's POSIX-compliant version of `printf` is in use).

Comment: My question is not just whether it contains a `:`, but what it _does_ contain. `ls`'s behavior in presence of nonprintable characters is undefined by the POSIX standard and varies between implementations, as the above-linked wiki page describes; thus, the value of using a hex editor to view a dump in a printable form.

Comment: BTW, consider `adb shell sh -xc 'su -c "ls ..."'` to get a log of the exact `ls` invocation _after_ the remote shell has expanded the glob.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217221/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-a-abramov).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy please note that the OP is asking about Android shell. It looks a lot like a POSIX shell at first glance but is actually a very limited set of simlinks to a binary called 'toobox' which is Googles stripped down version of toolbox. It does not have printf and lacks many other utilities of a normal POISX shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy when running with sh -xc i get a literal parsing of the wildcard, i.e no such file or directory ls ... -*. also, `printf '%q\n' /data/data/com.kauf.wrapmyFaceFunphotoeditor/files/DV-*` returns bad %q@2

Comment: After trying out a few things, I am not sure there is a way to make this specific for work given all the limitations of the system. So I deleted my answer for now.

Comment: @A.Abramov, _nod_, `%q` only works with bash or ksh, and it sounds like you have just basic `sh`.

Comment: @LevM. it actually does have printf, and thats how we solved this issue.

Comment: @A.Abramov interesting is it a modded ROM? Glad you got it solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), `ls`'s behavior is not always well-defined. It's generally safer to use NULs (if you don't have any control or knowledge of filenames) or newlines (if you have reason to be certain that filenames can't contain them) to directly delimit a list of values emitted by the shell. Consider, then:

```
# output is separated by NULs, which cannot possibly exist in filenames
printf '%s\0' /data/data/com.kauf.wrapmyfacefunphotoeditor/files/DV-*
```

...or...

```
# output is separated by newlines; beware of a file named DV-evil<newline>something-else
printf '%s\n' /data/data/com.kauf.wrapmyfacefunphotoeditor/files/DV-*
```

Note that if you're passing this through extra unescaping layers, it may be necessary to double up your backslashes -- if you see literal `0`s or `n`s separating filenames in your output, that's evidence of same.

---

Note also that if *no* matching files exist, a glob will expand to itself, so you can get an output that contains only the literal string `/data/data/com.kauf.wrapmyfacefunphotoeditor/files/DV-*`; in bash this can be suppressed with `shopt -s nullglob`, but with `/bin/sh` (particularly the minimal busybox versions more likely to be available on Android) this may not be available. One way to work around this is with code similar to the following:

```
# set list of files into $1, $2, etc
set -- /data/data/com.kauf.wrapmyfacefunphotoeditor/files/DV-*
# exit immediately if $1 does not exist
if [ "$#" -le 1 ] && [ ! -e "$1" ]; then
  exit
fi
# otherwise, print the list in our desired format
printf '%s\0' "$@"
```

Comment: Charles, your answer is great and you've helped me understand this much better in the chat as well. Your bounty will be well deserved ( once I can turn it in), and you also have my thanks.